# Kotlin coroutines thread pools and Java equivalent

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, concurrency, threadpool, kotlin-coroutines

I see from the doc for `val IO: CoroutineDispatcher` that the created executor limits to 64 threads unless we set specific limit.
This seems to me that it is equivalent to a [newFixedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)).
Is there in Kotlin coroutines something equivalent to a [newCachedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()) ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no an equivalent to `newCachedThreadPool` in Kotlin coroutines, but you can convert it to `CoroutineDispatcher` by applying [`asCoroutineDispatcher()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/as-coroutine-dispatcher.html) extension function:

```
Executors.newCachedThreadPool().asCoroutineDispatcher()
```